# Deploy same image two different namespaces same port

Tags: kubernetes

I have a single node k8s cluster. I have two namespaces, call them `n1` and `n2`. I want to deploy the same image, on the same port but in different namespaces.

How do I do this?

namespace yamls:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: n1

and

apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: n2
```

service yamls:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app-n1
  namespace: n1
  labels:
    app: my-app-n1
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: my-app-n1

and

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app-n2
  namespace: n2
  labels:
    app: my-app-n2
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: my-app-n2
```

deployment yamls:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app-n1
  labels:
    app: my-app-n1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app-n1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app-n1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: waiter
        image: waiter:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

and

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app-n2
  labels:
    app: my-app-n2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app-n2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app-n2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: waiter
        image: waiter:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

`waiter:v1` corresponds to this repo: https://hub.docker.com/r/adamgardnerdt/waiter

Surely I can do this as namespaces are supposed to represent different environments? eg. nonprod vs. prod. So surely I can deploy identically into two different "environments" aka "namespaces"?

Comment: what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: Do you want to do this to run the deployment in different namespaces for different environments like staging, production etc. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Service you have specified namespaces , that is correct.

For Deployments you should also specify **namespaces othervise they will go to default namespace.**

**Example:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app-n1
  namespace: n1
  labels:
    app: my-app-n1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app-n1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app-n1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: waiter
        image: waiter:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to deploy the same image, on the same port but in different namespaces.

You are already doing that with your configs, except for `deployment` objects, that should refer to correct namespaces (as mentioned by answer from **Ijaz Ahmad Khan**), available to other services in the namespaces using DNS names `my-app-n1` and `my-app-n2` respectively.

Because `waiter` is a web server, I assume you would like to access both instances of it from the internet. Hence, you should:

- change the type of both services to `ClusterIP`,
- add `ingress` object, one per each namespace, containing a host name, e.g. `myapp.com` and `staging.myapp.com` respectively),
- put a load balancer in front of your cluster: the load balancer will use ingress objects to know which hostname matches which service (your cloud provider should create a load balancer automatically).